# Ruby bubble sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ruby, sorting

I'm just looking for constructive criticism of my Ruby implementation of a bubble sort algorithm.

```
class BubbleSorter < Object
  def bubble_sort(list)
    swaps = 0
    # parse the list until it is sorted
    until @sorted == true
      # run the comparison of adjacent elements
      for i in 0...(list.length - 1)
        # if the first is greater than the second, swap them with parallel assignment
        if list[i] > list[i+1]
          list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
          # increase the number of swaps performed in this run by 1
          swaps += 1
        end
        # compare the next 2 elements
        i += 1
      end

      # uncomment the following line to see each iteration:
      # p list

    # If any swaps took place during the last run, the list is not yet sorted
    if swaps > 0
        @sorted = false
      # no swaps? Everything is in order
      else
        @sorted = true
      end
      # reset swap count for each run
      swaps = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you should comment your work, some of your comments seem unecessary. Let's look at some lines to see why:

```
# parse the list until it is sorted
until @sorted == true
```

The comment seems redundant. Your line of code `until @sorted == true` reads clear enough for me to understand that you want to keep doing something until the list is sorted.

```
# if the first is greater than the second, swap them with parallel assignment
if list[i] > list[i+1]
  list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
```

This code is also pretty self explanatory. If you did have a comment you should be explaining **why** you do this. However, bubblesort is pretty well known so you probably don't even need a comment on this.

```
# increase the number of swaps performed in this run by 1
swaps += 1
```

Again **why**? I can read the code, it is obvious you're incrementing the number of `swaps`. I would omit.

```
# compare the next 2 elements
i += 1
```

Based of the `if` statement I would know that this the purpose of `i`. I would omit it, **but** it does explain why you increment `i`, so there is some grey zone here.

You write some good comments toward the end, let's analyze why they are good:

```
# If any swaps took place during the last run, the list is not yet sorted
if swaps > 0
    @sorted = false
# no swaps? Everything is in order
else
  @sorted = true
```

It explains **why** we need to check if `swaps > 0` and how the sorting algorithm depends on this.

Answer (score 1):

#### No need for `@sorted` variable

You can remove the `@sorted` variable and return directly if no swaps were performed, change the loop to `while true` and add `return if swaps == 0` instead of the `if swaps ... @sorted =...` statements.

#### No need for a class

You also do not need a class for this, you can either write a top-level function or put it into a module, a class is used to hold data and functions to operate on it, a class that holds a single static function is unreasonable.

#### Ruby `step` method

You should use the `.step(2)` method as it is more explicit than manual incrementing and modyfing a loop variable inside the body is unusual and breaks the expectation that we already know how many times a `for` loop should run.